# What is the best strategy for quickly getting Badass tokens?

Tags: borderlands-2

There are a lot of Badass Challenges - so many I can't easily keep track of them all.  Sometimes I seem to be completing them constantly, and at other times I go a long time without completing any.  I see a clear benefit to getting a lot of Badass tokens, since it offers an upgrade to all of your characters.  What challenges should I focus on to get Badass tokens as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Switch up weapons - you get challenges for number of kills with each type.
- Switch up elementals - again challenges for number of kills.
- Switch up grenade types - there are challenges for using each one.
- Switch up shield types - there are challenges for kills with fire novas, 'roid kills, etc.
- Each map has a set of challenges, beat bosses in a particular way or find hidden symbols and the like.
- You can follow a particular challenge if you're close to completing it, which bumps it to the top of the challenge list.
- As you progress the challenges get harder, but have greater rewards.

Comment: Annoyingly enough the Watched challenge list isn't kept after closing the game. Actually it's not kept *inside* a game. Watched challenges disappear almost immediately, I recommend not even trying the feature, as, at least on PC, it's frustrating as hell.

Comment: Good answer.  Also note that it can pay to switch grenade types!

Comment: And shield types! It pays to know which special shield/grenade types have challenges so you know which to use, especially when going back to do Trivial missions, so you can do stuff like use grenades you otherwise never use on weaker enemies for easy kills

Comment: @peacedog cheers, added that

Comment: @BenBrocka cheers, added that too

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you have a friend who is willing to assist you with it, and assuming you do not mind a tactic that is considered somewhat "degenerate", you can quickly rack up large amounts of Badass Ranks by repeatedly completing the Level 5 "Psst, Hey, Buddy..." challenge. This requires trading with another player a total of 50 times, but no loot or money needs to pass hands - merely the act of initiating and finalizing an empty trade will give you credit toward the challenge. Each new character pair that you and your friend create and perform the 50 trades with will earn you a total of 166 Badass Ranks, which apply to all your characters. Characters used for this can then be deleted and recreated to harvest further Badass Ranks.

Edit: It should be noted that one of the PC/Steam patches for Borderlands 2 may have removed this trick. Those with the Gearbox guns due to Premiere Club membership can use these to have something to trade.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I think that can be done, even in a less-degenerate way.  It is still a valuable tip, even if I do it only on one character instead of farming it.  It's a quick one, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: On the PC, at least, they patched the game so you do have to trade an item for the trade to count.

Comment: You can do it even faster by trading 3,000,001 credits back and forth, to quickly hit rank 5 on the wealth challenge.  One trade seems much faster than 50, although you do have to have the 3 mil first.

Answer (score 6):

Collect a total of $3,000,000 on one character, make a new character and trade the 3 mill to the new character. it will give you the badass ranks for fully completeing the $3 million challenge.  simply trade the money back to the main character and save and quit with the new one. delete the new character and make a new one... just lather, rinse, and repeate.  seems like its tedious, but it is a much quicker way to gain the badass ranks then trading with another person 50 times.

Answer (score 3):

Farming badass tokens is sort of an exploit in that you're not really getting a bonus for playing the game, but rather deliberately gaming the system.  You can always turn off the badass bonuses if you want so you're not really ruining the game for yourself.  That said, here's a method I've compiled.

I see two very quick ways to farm Badass tokens.  Both of them involve having a 2nd profile (e.g. a friend you trust or a free Xbox live silver account in addition to your main) that you can trade items and money to and trade back:

1. farming the "For the Horde" challenge
2. farming "Nothing rhymes with orange" challenge

My Method:

- i) You need to give the 2nd account 3 Million dollars and 15 orange items (these can be any level orange items, possibly items that you've duped or don't need anymore).
- ii) Once you've done that, create a new character on your main profile and join a game hosted by the 2nd account.
- iii) have the 2nd account trade 3 million dollars and 15 orange items to your newly created character.  this will complete 2 level 5 challenges (#1 and #2 above) giving you around 30 badass tokens.
- iv) trade the items and money back to the 2nd profile character and rejoin as a new character.  Repeat steps (i) through (iii).